# How deviation is plotted in Graph Results listener of Jmeter? If I have to plot graph manually in excel, what should i do for it?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In Jmeter, I have to export the execution data in excel so that i can create some custom graphs. But how I can plot the deviation graph, as same which is provided in Graph Results listener ? 
Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're about to analyze JMeter test results with Excel deviation can be calculated as below:

- [STDEVP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/stdevp-HP005209281.aspx) function
- inside JMeter deviation is calculated as follows:

  ```
  private void addValue(long newValue, int sampleCount) {
  count += sampleCount;
  double currentVal = newValue;
  sum += currentVal;
  if (sampleCount > 1){
      minimum=Math.min(newValue/sampleCount, minimum);
      maximum=Math.max(newValue/sampleCount, maximum);
      // For n values in an aggregate sample the average value = (val/n)
      // So need to add n * (val/n) * (val/n) = val * val / n
      sumOfSquares += (currentVal * currentVal) / (sampleCount);
  } else { // no point dividing by 1
      minimum=Math.min(newValue, minimum);
      maximum=Math.max(newValue, maximum);
      sumOfSquares += currentVal * currentVal;
  }
  // Calculate each time, as likely to be called for each add
  mean = sum / count;
  deviation = Math.sqrt((sumOfSquares / count) - (mean * mean));
  }
  ```

So in order to have deviation graph you need the following:

1. Run your test [in command line non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as `jmeter -n -t /path/to/test -l /path/to/results.csv`
2. Import results.csv file into spreadsheet application and calculate deviation as described above.